# Templated function is not able to multiply a value with -1

Tags: c++, g++, c++14

Watch at the following simple code, 
Compiling it with the command `g++ -std=c++14 -g -O2 CODE.cpp` 
 produces the strange Output :

`Why this ?? -2147483648`

```
# include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

# define pc(x)    putchar(x)

template <class T>
inline void pd(T num, char ch = ' '){

   num = -num;
   cout << "Why this ?? " << num << endl;

}

int main(void){

   pd(INT_MIN);

   return 0;
}
```

Please explain this behavior  !!

Comment: Two's complement...

Answer (score 2):

Type deduced for `INT_MIN` is `int`.
`-INT_MIN` may cause integer overflow (if `INT_MIN = -INT_MAX - 1` which is true on most platforms) and thus it causes undefined behaviour.